# Style two html form text area/inputs on same page differently

Tags: html, css, forms

I have two forms on my site but am struggling to style them differently.

I want all text areas/inputs on the website to have the same style except for one form.

So all forms on the site use this css...

```
input, textarea {
    background-color:#eae7e7 !important;
}
```

How do I go about changing the background color on another form as per below?

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
</div>
```

.form-control input, .form-control textarea doesn't seem to work?

Comment: After reading your question a few times it sounds like you are using the words "form" and "input" as though they are interchangeable

Comment: Sorry about that, but i have 20 forms and need to change only one of them - the one I have provided code for above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.form-control input, .form-control textarea
```

Seems that you have this kind of code :

```
<div class="form-control">
   <input>
</div>
```

Your CSS selector should be like this :

```
input.form-control, textarea.form-control don't forget the `!important` when you apply the css property
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to add an id to the form in question:

```
<div class="form-control" id="my-form">
```

Then, style the inputs in css like:

```
#my-form input {your-style:value;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
input.form-control {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

You'll have to add `!important` to your css also in order to overwrite the styles applied to `input, textarea`. However, if possible, you should remove the `!important` altogether unless 100% necessary.

Comment: Remove the spaces between `input` and `.form-control` in your selector (I think)

Comment: Could leave the space out for sure, I just left the space intentionally since it seemed like `.form-control` was added uniquely to this input in particular.

Comment: Actually nope you are 100% right, not sure why I assumed it was inside the input. Thanks for catching that!